# Halloween: gender and h muet/aspiré

Tags: genre, contractions

Normally it seems that words beginning with *H* that are borrowed into French from another language are masculine and have an *h aspiré*: *le hockey, le haïku, le hamster*.

In Quebec, at least, *Halloween* is different - it seems to be feminine with an *h muet*, at least if you look at the search results at [*Le Devior*](https://www.ledevoir.com/recherche?expression=halloween) or [*Radio-Canada*](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/recherche?pageNumber=1&q=halloween&sort=-relevance). Quebec's office of the French language (OQLF) [has declared](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2176) that *Halloween* is indeed feminine and has an *h muet*.

On the other hand, at Lawless French, *Halloween* is on the [big list of words](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/h-aspire/) with an *h aspiré*, and there's a [transcript of a monologue](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/listening/toussaint/) by a native speaker from France who uses *"de Halloween"* and *"d'Halloween"* within the same paragraph!

Finally, Google returns about three times as many results for *"Joyeux Halloween"* as it does for *"Joyeuse Halloween"*, implying that the masculine version is more popular.

Outside of the OQLF, is there a consensus on the gender and, um, "muet-ness" of this word?

Comment: We didn't use to celebrate Halloween in France (and to this day nobody I know in France celebrates it). First time I heard of it was in connection with the American movie of that name. I'm not surprised a native French person wouldn't be sure how to pronounce it and whether to use d' or de.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vous pouvez trouver une bonne analyse ici https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/orthographe-halloween.

**Résumé :**

- Le mot est féminin ; mais il n'est guère employé avec une ou un adjectif.
- On dit joyeuse Halloween quand même.
- Le mot est employé sans déterminant. En France, on dit 'fêter Halloween'.
- H aspiré ou muet, l'usage hésite. Selon les dictionnaires H est aspiré. Mais les deux variantes sont répandues à l'oral.

NB

Voir aussi le commentaire de @Personne :

Domicilié dans l'hexagone depuis toujours, j'ai toujours entendu « joyeuse [fête d']allo-ouine » ; j'en ai conclu que le mot était féminin et sans H aspiré.

Comment: Domicilié dans l'hexagone depuis toujours, j'ai toujours entendu « joyeuse [fête d']allo-ouine » ; j'en ai conclu que le mot était féminin et sans H aspiré … tenir compte que je ne siège pas à l'Académie française :-)

Comment: @Personne Tout à fait et c'est ce qui est confirmé dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en Langue Française* (Sld. A. Rey).

Comment: Au Québec, on dit « fêter l'Halloween » avec l'article. Un québécois m'a dit que certains enfants là-bas croient que la fête s'appelle « la Louine ».

Comment: @CanadianYankee Je pense que la majorité des enfants d'âge d'école primaire (et pas que) ne saurait ni écrire Halloween (à supposer qu'il y ait une orthographe !) ni le découper en syllabe, d'autant plus que c'est une apparition récente en France. C'est le même genre de phénomène qui fait qu'un grand nombre d'adultes  écrivent « une ascenseur » ! (et « l'ascenseur elle... »).

Comment: Avant que cette question ne soit posée, je n'aurais jamais imaginé qu'Halloween puisse être utilisé au féminin et encore moins que ce soit le genre indiqué dans les dictionnaires. Ta réponse devrait être plus nuancée. Je n'aurais pas repris l'affirmation *on dit joyeuse Halloween quand même* sans m'assurer que c'était le cas alors que j'ai la conviction que c'est majoritairement le masculin qui est utilisé en France et à l'inverse, majoritairement ou exclusivement le féminin au Québec où la chose a dû arriver bien plus tôt que chez nous autres...

Comment: Mon emploi c'est surtout _passer l'Halloween_, _que fais-tu à/pour l'Halloween_, _des bonbons d'Halloween_. J'ai été un peu surpris par le féminin, et ça ne vient pas avec une explication. J'en déduis que c'est l'influence judéo-chrétienne vu que c'est la _veille de la Toussaint_, deux noms féminins, et le fait que bien des fêtes courantes soient de genre féminin. Mais mon réflexe c'est de dire _un bel Halloween_ avec l'adjectif, et je vois le gars de _l'Oreille tendue_ il a _un très joyeux Halloween_, et je ferais la liaison là. Les résultats ds LeDevoir/R-C ne sont pas aussi tranchés que ça.

Comment: Je trouve le féminin acceptable aussi, mais plus populaire. Ça arrive assez souvent que dans un cas où j'entends les deux genres, je trouve qu'un des emplois est d'un registre un peu différent. Par ailleurs je trouve que le mot « sonne » féminin. Je dirais aussi que je prononce ça comme un francophone de Montréal parlant aussi l'anglais donc très différemment de _allo_ et _ouine_ et pas mal plus comme en anglais. J'écrivais ce mot à l'école primaire et ça fait un bon bout ! Je pense que je trouve des phrases avec Halloween comme sujet suivi d'un attribut inusitées, l'adjectif m'est plus fam.

Comment: @Personne Mais « joyeux Halloween » et « joyeuse Halloween » sont quasiment homophones, avec un H muet ; comment pouvez-vous affirmer que votre interlocuteur dis l'un plutôt que l'autre ?

Comment: @Blackhole — Je n'affirme pas, je témoigne seulement de ce que j'ai entendu d'Halloween quand j'étais jeune, fête que personne de ma famille n'a jamais organisé. Comme je l'ai suggéré par des [ ], à l'oreille, ce mot reste rattaché/associé à la notion féminine de fête … c'est la première fois que je l'écris ici !

Answer (score 5):

Loanwords won't necessarily take the masculine gender, it might depend on the word ending or its morphological or semantical similarity with its French counterpart.

In any case, usage decides what gender will end up in the dictionary entry. And this entry is more likely to change to reflect what native speakers think than those speakers are likely to comply with the prescriptions from a dictionary. Moreover, usage sometimes varies between Québec and European French, and between prescriptive usage and casual use. For instance, a well known and recent example is *covid*, a feminine word in Québec because of *d(isease)* associated to *(la) maladie*, while in France, despite the "official" feminine gender, speakers overwhelmingly use *le covid* because it is associated with *le (corona)virus*. Endless discussions about one gender or another being "correct" are pointless, as is discussing *[le sexe des anges](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/discuter-sur-le-sexe-des-anges)*.

The gender of Halloween doesn't matter that much because whether you use the masculine or feminine wouldn't prevent the word from being understood. I guess the feminine can be explained by an implicit *fête*: *Souhaiter une bonne fête d'Halloween* →  *Souhaiter une bonne Halloween* or because the word ending sounds like *-ine* which is a feminine one in French. I would nevertheless always say ***Un** bon Halloween* if I had to.

The gender of holidays is often feminine (*Une Pâques, La Pentecôte, La Toussaint*) but the gender might vary with Christmas (*Un Noël blanc*, *Des cadeaux pour la Noël*, *des cadeaux pour le Noël des enfants*, ...).

As for whether the *H* should be *aspiré* or not, my feeling is the *liaison* is always done in France, so the word breaks the rule stating non Latin words should have an *H aspiré*.

Comment: @λyoyedoncques 

Answer (score 4):

To contrast with Dimitris' answer, as a native French speaker (from France), "*une Halloween*" feels weird.

It's pretty rare to say "*un/une Halloween*" or to use adjectives with it, so few people will have a strong opinion about it, but it seems that the masculine is predominant in France, while the feminine is used more in Quebec.

Here's some results in google news for "*une halloween*":

[image]

---

Other examples in official French translations:

- [Un Halloween Terrifiant](https://playoverwatch.com/fr-fr/events/halloween-terror/) from the video game Overwatch
- [Un Halloween spécial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewoeSqJ7n7U) from Disney Channel
- [Joyeux Halloween, Scooby-Doo!](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyeux_Halloween,_Scooby-Doo!), a Scooby-Doo movie.

It seems that when big companies need an official French translation, they go for a masculine Halloween.

---

On "muet-ness", I'd say the *h muet* is strongly predominant. You'll find many mentions of "*soirée d'Halloween*" or "*fête d'Halloween*", and The jack-o'-lantern is called ["*citrouille d'Halloween*"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-o%27-lantern), I've never seen "*de Halloween*".

Comment: *Dictionnaire culturel en Langue Française* (sld Alain Rey) : « **Halloween**  n.f. etc... ” Donc attesté comme **féminin**. D'ailleurs la référence de Dimitris, bien qu'un site commercial, est un site que je qualifierais de fiable. Plus fiable en tout cas que beaucoup de journalistes et titreurs de la presse régionale en France.

Comment: @None Encore un cas de l'usage vs la norme :) Je n'ai trouvé aucun dictionnaire qui l'atteste au masculin, mais l'usage en France semble en majorité préférer le masculin au féminin.

Comment: Aren't you contradicting yourself?  In your answer you  say  "une Halloween" feels weird and "the masculine is predominant in France" and only selected examples where it is used in the masculine. In your comment you write "*l'usage en France semble à très grande majorité le préférer au féminin*".  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @None Ma formulation était maladroite, j'ai édité mon commentaire. (*le* renvoyait à *le masculin*, et pas à *Halloween*)

Comment: Technically speaking it is not my answer:-)! I just make a googling and I found something that it seemed to be trustworthy.

Comment: As a matter of fact, dictionaries say that the word is a feminine one. https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/Halloween/38914 ; https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/halloween

Comment: @Dimitris I know, that's what I said in a previous comment. I found no dictionaries where the word is masculine.

Comment: https://www.lewebmestrepedagogique.com/2010/10/halloween-ou-halloween/ souhaite quand même "Une amusante et effrayante Halloween à tous!" quand même:-!

Comment: My answer agrees with yours in a couple of points. I also said that "Le mot est employé sans déterminant. "; "l n'est guère employé avec une ou un adjectif."

Comment: @Dimitris Je l'ai trouvé aussi, et en cherchant un peu, tout semble indiquer que la personne qui gère ce site vit au Québec. Dans cet article il parle de l'état du français dans l'enseignement (et cite le Québec) et parle de ses parents, qui ont fait "comme des milliers de parents au Québec" https://www.lewebmestrepedagogique.com/2008/09/cest-en-septembre/

Comment: @Dimitris Sur ça T. a raison tu cites un site Québécois, ça ne va pas!!!!

Comment: h muet is silent h. Why not say it? Just wondering.

Comment: @Lambie Simplement pour reprendre les termes de la question, ça ne va pas plus loin.

Comment: @None En effet, toutes les sources que j'ai trouvées pour "*une Halloween*" viennent du Québec. Je serai ravi d'ajouter des exemples du féminin dans un texte venant de France, je n'en ai simplement pas trouvé. Les seules exceptions étant les dictionnaires, et page Wikipedia d'Halloween (qui ne dit jamais un/une mais l'accorde au féminin, probablement sur base des dictionnaires justement)

Comment: @Lambie Both the *h muet* and the *h aspiré* are functionally silent - the difference is whether they allow a liaison with a preceding word. Because this is a something particular to French without any equivalent in English, it's my experience that the French terms *muet* and *aspiré* are often used even in English discussions of French words beginning with 'h' to avoid the impression that one is phonologically silent and the other aspirated. See [here](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/h-aspire/) for an example.

Comment: @CanadianYankee You didn't get what I was saying. Why is everyone using h aspiré and h muet and in italics when those terms **in English** are aspirated h and silent h? One can talk about things in another language when something doesn't, as it were, "exist" in it. Anyway, the name comes from Old French, so understanding it is not based on translating the word aspirated.